# How to stop a observable timer

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code for a timer and I need to stop it with an if statement in this way.

```
imageSource;
status;
subscription: Subscription;
everyFiveSeconds: Observable<number> = timer(0, 5000);
constructor(private apiSvc:AuthenticationService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription = this.everyFiveSeconds.subscribe(() => {
  this.getImageQR();
  this.disactivate();
 });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

getImageQR() {
 this.apiSvc.getQR().subscribe((rsp: any) => {
  console.log(rsp);
  this.status = rsp.accountStatus;
  let imageBinary = rsp.qrCode;
  this.imageSource = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(imageBinary);
 });
}

private disactivate() {
 if (this.status == 'athenticated') {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
```

But it does not work with the `ngOnDestroy` function nor with the `disactivate` function.

I need to stop the timer when `this.status = rsp.accountStatus;` is equal to 'athenticated'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `takeUntil` pattern:

```js
  destroy$ = new Subject();

  everyFiveSeconds: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.everyFiveSeconds.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.destroy$.next(); //whenever you want to "unsubscribe"
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kghf9c)

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, I was not clear on what I need, this code works but I need to stop the timer when `this.status = rsp.accountStatus;` is equal to 'athenticated', I will update the question, I'm very sorry

Comment: Hey, no worries. You can use the `this.destroy$.next()` line inside the if statement you have then; wouldn't that work?

Comment: You mean put this inside the `disactivate` function? `      this.everyFiveSeconds.subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.destroy$.next(); //whenever you want to "unsubscribe"
        }, 3000);
      });`

Comment: No, just put the `this.destroy$.next();` line above your `this.subscription.unsubscribe();` line. Don't forget to pipe the `takeUntil` in the `timer`

Comment: Ok I put it but doesn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong but thanks for the help